# How to know which user created a Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

I'm developing a php web interface which allows creating mysql database and user.

To avoid using the mysql root user I created a special one called mysqlcreator which can create users, create and show databases, and grant his same privileges to the users that creates.

```
CREATE USER 'mysqlcreator'@'localhost' IDETIFIED BY 'randompassword';

GRANT CREATE USER, CREATE, SHOW DATABASES, GRANT OPTION ON *.* TO 'mysqlcreator'@'localhost';
```

So , if mysqlcreator creates new users granting them CREATE privilege, they will be able to create databases, and will have all the privileges on the databases that they have created, but not on others. This is the easiest solution that I found out to acheive my goal . (but maybe there are better ones)

I would like now to show a list of databases showing which user has privileges on each of them, but I am not  able to figure out how to do that.

I've been looking in mysql database (procs_priv, db) and also tried with `show create database` but with no luck.

Any help would be apreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Would this be a step forward? : MySQL accounts correspond to rows in the mysql.user table. When a client connects successfully, the server authenticates the client to a particular row in this table. The User and Host column values in this row uniquely identify the account and correspond to the 'user_name'@'host_name' format in which account names are written in SQL statements. ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-activity-auditing.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I discovered that what I want to do is not possible with mysql. It could be possible with Oracle. Then I realized that these users could create databases and tables within them, but nothing more (no insert, no select). The need somebody to grant them these privileges....si I didn't solve the problem ....I still need a root user